# Backbone.js text change event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How do I trigger a `change` event on textbox in a backbone view?

I tried:

```
events: {
    "onChanged input.autocomplete": "update"
}
```

`update` didn't get fired. I also tried `change`.

What is the name of the event for textchange?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work:

```
events: {
    "change input.autocomplete": "update"
}
```

1. Is the selector (input.autocomplete) correct?
2. Change fires on blur, not on keydown - does this agree with your requirement?

Comment: 2. I want a feature similar to an autocomplete, so I guess I have to write for keyup/keydown events